# Active menu entry for custom taxonomy - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have a custom post type and a custom taxonomy. Each custom post type is assigned to exactly one term. I added a menu entry for each term in my custom taxonomy. Behind each of menu entries is a overview page with all the custom posts assigned to this term. If you click on one of the customs posts a details page opens. But if you are on a details page the corresponding menu entry for the taxonomy term is no longer marked as active. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know this is an old thread but a) did you manage to find a final solution and b) would that solution possibly include the nav menu walker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the following solution for my problem:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);

function special_nav_class($classes, $item) {
    global $naventries;
    $naventries[$item->ID] = $item;
    if($item->type == 'taxonomy') {
        global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $item->object);

        $currentTerms = array();
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            foreach($terms as $term) {
                $currentTerms[] = $term->slug;
            }
        }

        if(is_array($currentTerms) && count($currentTerms) > 0) {
            $currentTerm = get_term($item->object_id, $item->object);
            if(in_array($currentTerm->slug, $currentTerms)) {
                $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
            }
        }
    } 

     return $classes;
}
```

But there is still one problem left. I also want to add the class *current-menu-ancestor* to the parent element. I have the id of the parent element via `$item->menu_item_parent` but no idea how I can use this id to change the classes of the corresponding menu entry at this point?

Comment: In some cases there is no term. You should avoid looping through empty array. Put conditional `if( $terms && !is_wp_error($terms) )` before `foreach` loop

Comment: Did you ever find out how to add the *current-menu-ancestor* class?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Active state if you have a pagetitle on the result page
    var currentTitle = $('.header h2').html();
    $('.nav ul.menu li').find(':contains('+currentTitle+')').parent().addClass('current-menu-item');
</script>
```

So my solution works if you have a page title with the same name as the menu item
you would like to add the class `current-page-item` to.

Ofcourse, you need jQuery installed to get this working.

edit: Make sure you put this underneath the loop on your archive-taxonomy page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var title = $(document).attr('title');

        $(".maincat-list li a:contains('"+title+"')").css("text-decoration", "underline");

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for some time. This is how I solved my problem.

1. Go into wordpress backend -> appearance -> menu
2. Add some custom class to the menu item that you want active on your taxonomy or archive page (if you dont see the css class option go to the screen options and activate it). For example I put the class 'active' on the menu item.
3. Go to archive.php or taxonomy.php or whatever template you are using and add some style for the .active class you just added, like:

> ```
> <style>
> .menu li.active {
> background-color:#000;
> }
> </style>
> ```

You can use other methods to inject the css into the archive page of course.